# attaching DOM event handlers from a plugin that loads asynchronously?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery plugin that loads asynchronously and attaches events to a DOM element on page load.

Intermittently the DOM elements are not attached with events from the plugin - This happens due to the loading of these DOM elements via another javascript file.

Is there any way to ensure that event handlers are always attached to DOM elements?

Comment: You'll have to show some code, it's basically impossible to answer this question in the abstract. What do you mean by it loads "asynchronously"? What do you mean by "intermittently" handlers don't get attached? Give an example, and people can help you understand why it's not working.

Comment: The code is messy and huge and present in multiple files, I wish I could provide code for better resolution.

Comment: @ web_dev: Then create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/). Two reasons for doing that (at least): 1. Usually, in the process of doing that, you figure out the problem. 2. In the rare case where that doesn't happen, you have something other people can reasonably help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main answer here is that if you're writing a *plug-in*, it's not your problem to attach it to the right elements on page load (or at any other time). That's for the *user* of your plug-in to do. It's not in your problem domain.

But if you want to try to handle it:

You can ensure that the page is fully loaded by using the jQuery [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) handler, which has as shortcut (just pass a function into `jQuery`), e.g.:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // ...here, all page elements defined by the main HTML have been created
});
```

If you need to handle elements that are added *after* the page is fully loaded, look at using *event delegation*. That's where you handle events not on the elements themselves, but on their ancestor elements, when the events bubble up to them. For instance, this will handle any `click` event on an element with class `foo` unless the event is cancelled by a handler attached closer to the element:

```
$(document.body).delegate(".foo", "click", function() {
    // An element matching ".foo" was clicked
});
```

What [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) does is hook the event on the element you call it on (`document.body`, in this case), but then only trigger the handler if the actual click had a matching element in the ancestory path from the element where the click actually occurred, to its parent, to *its* parent, and so on until the element on which you called `delegate`.

With recent versions of jQuery, you can also use the hyper-overloaded [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function to do the same thing (note the order of the args is different):

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".foo", function() {
    // An element matching ".foo" was clicked
});
```

I prefer `delegate` for clarity.

But again, it's really not your problem. It's up to the users of the plug-in to know when, and where, to hook it up.

Comment: delegate helped achieve what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The events from the plugin (is it yours) must be delegated.

Take a look at the jQuery documentation about [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or, even better, [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Concretely, you bind your event to a dom element that exists and will always exists (the dom element that will receive the content of the asynchronously loaded data), and you specify a selector that will match your concrete element to listen :

```
jQuery('#my_container_for_ajax')
    .on ('click', '.my_future .elements .tolisten', function () {});
```